# Why i am unable to import fluttertoast package to my project

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently unable to import fluttertoast in my project!

My pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_insta: ^0.1.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
```

I also see it in pubspec.lock

```
fluttertoast:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: fluttertoast
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.1.8"
```

but when I try to import it, I get

```
error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [feed_preview] lib\main.dart:4)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Did you try get and update commands?

Comment: I did run them!

Comment: @dude ^7.1.6 means that anything over that goes. Also that was what was specified on pub.dev

Comment: @Dude that does not fix the problem. I have tried formatting it in many ways (^7.1.8 ^7.1.6 and both without the ^) without luck!

Comment: any luck here? I have been trying to use it too.. doesn't work. My error says 
"The imported package 'fluttertoast' isn't a dependency of the importing package"

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter clean 
flutter packages get
```